# "object is not callable" Why is my function not callable?

Tags: python, class

In my training dataset, I am trying to call a function that is charge in my training dataset which I am trying to call that function but I am getting an error that I can't call my function I don't understand why it's not moving previously was working perfectly.

Here is my code

```
class TrainDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        # Get one item from the dataset
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
```

And I am trying to call it by my own parameters.

```
TrainDataset = TrainDataset(x,y)
```

Now I am facing this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-18c28e7d7416> in <module>
----> 1 TrainDataset = TrainDataset(x,y)

TypeError: 'TrainDataset' object is not callable
```

Comment: You can't use the same name for a variable and a class (or a function). Use a different variable name, like `train_dataset = TrainDataset(x,y)`.

Comment: @Craig: You could do it, once. After that though, the instance would replace the class, so no more instances could be created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reassigned the class to a variable

```
TrainDataset = TrainDataset(x,y)
```

Then that variable is not callable, so you can't make that class anymore

[Variables shouldn't start with capital letters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), anyway